# How to avoid observable calculation on each subscription?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, subscription, ngxs

I have the next code:

```
this.currency$ = combineLatest([
  this.currency.valueChanges, // Currency ID Form Control (selected currency id)
  this.currencies$, // A list of currencies, that is loaded from backend
]).pipe(
  map((result: [number, Currency[]]) => {
    // todo: optimize - do not loop over all, stop when found
    let currencyName = '';
    if (result[1]) {
      result[1].forEach((currency: Currency) => {
        if (currency.id === this.currency.value) {
          currencyName = currency.name;
        }
      });
    }

    return currencyName;
  })
);
```

The problem is, when I subscribe in the template to the currency$ observable, using the `| async` pipe - The calculation (determination of the currency name) happens twice.

What is a good solution, to calculate it only once and on every subscription, emit already calculated currency name? Of course I could add a component variable and preserve name there, but I would like to use observables, so the component should not have it's own state...

Comment: what does the currency$ Observable do ?

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid this by using **shareReplay Operator**  https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/multicasting/sharereplay to share the source and it the calculation will be done just once

```
  import { map, shareReplay } from 'rxjs/operators';
  ...


  this.currency$ = combineLatest([
  this.currency.valueChanges, // Currency ID Form Control (selected currency id)
  this.currencies$, // A list of currencies, that is loaded from backend
]).pipe(
  map((result: [number, Currency[]]) => {
    // todo: optimize - do not loop over all, stop when found
    let currencyName = '';
    if (result[1]) {
      result[1].forEach((currency: Currency) => {
        if (currency.id === this.currency.value) {
          currencyName = currency.name;
        }
      });
    }

    return currencyName;
  }),
  shareReplay() // here 
);
```

on this other hand avoid using multiple async pipe on your template, you can use an ng-container to set the value of your async pipe result to a variable and use it everywhere in your template

```
<ng-container *ngIf="currency$ | async as curency">
  // use currency here
</ng-container>
```